# why my code make dead-loop,it is about 'iter(c,a)'

Tags: python

```
def c():
    yield 222
    yield 333

a=[1,2,3,4]
b=iter(c,333)
print a,b
for i in b:
    print i
```

how can i get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the function (which will return the next value) to your `iter()` call. In your case, that's `c().next` rather than `c`.

This snippet below works as expected by producing all the yielded values up to, but exclusive of, the terminating value.

```
def generator():
    yield 1
    yield 2
    yield 3
    yield -1

sequence = iter (generator().next, -1)
print sequence
for value in sequence:
    print value
```

The output of that is:

```
pax> python prog1.py
    <callable-iterator object at 0xb77dd6ac>
    1
    2
    3
pax> _
```

Comment: @zjm1126, I think you're after the second variant. Modifying the answer to make that clear.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't call c().

Your question is cryptic. I don't know what you expect.

Please, edit the question and add information about what you thought that would do, and what you've observed instead.

Comment: Cryptic is too kind a euphemism for "illiterate."

Comment: @Seth - come on.  the OP tried, but I'd say that English isn't the native language.  "illiterate" is a bit harsh

Answer (score 1):

iter takes a callable and a sentinel and calls the callable repeatedly. Calling c repeatedly creates new generators which is not what you want. You want to call c once and then repeatedly call the next function, so try this instead:

```
def c():
    yield 222
    yield 333

a=[1,2,3,4]
b=iter(c().next, 333)
print a,b
for i in b:
    print i
```

Output:

```
222
```

Comment: Saying nothing against @paxdiablo; this was the first correct answer.

Comment: @Adam Bernier: out of interest - how can you see which answer was first? All I see is 'answered 1 hour ago' for both. I know that the exact timestamps will appear tomorrow, but how would I find that out now. (PS: I already know I was first, I'm just curious how you would investigate it).

Comment: Hmm... I just sorted by 'newest' and mine comes before paxdiablo. I guess that's how to find out. But Andrea Ambu comes before me, though his answer was not as complete as mine, and he later edited it. I can't see how to tell whether he edited his answer before or after I submitted mine. Why don't SO just print the timestamps?!

Comment: @Mark Byers:  yeah, for now, hover your mouse over the relative times.  In this case, of course I also took into account the time @paxdiablo edited his answer.

Comment: @Adam: Ah, thank you. That is an excellent tip (about the mouseover)! I hadn't noticed that.

Answer (score 0):

Because `c` never *returns* 333.

When using a *sentinel* in `iter` the first argument **must** be a callable, and `iter` will *yield* the returning value of the first argument until this value is equal to the sentinel.

What you'd like to do should be something like:

```
def c():
     yield 222
     yield 333


a=[1,2,3,4]
b=iter(c().next,333)
print a,b
for i in b:
    print i
```